# Прикрепить меню к верху (без прокрутки)

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Меню выводится в середине страницы(так нужно для СЕО). Как его можно перенести стилями на самый верх, сдвинув остальные элементы? Разметка при этом не должна меняться с помощью js. При прокрутке прилипать оно так же не должно.
Спасибо.

Comment: Приведите Ваш код, пожалуйста.

Comment: Если упрощенно, то
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="menu"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
Полный код привести не смогу, он разбит на десяток вьюх. И меню должно быть вверху

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать так: 
меню позиционировать абсолютно, а контейнеру задать отступ сверху на высоту самого меню, тем самым сдвинув его.

```css
.menu{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
 }
 
 .container{
  padding-top: высота меню
 }
```

Или попробовать с помощью Flexbox. 
Общему родителю указать 
 `display: flex;` и  `flex-direction: column;`(для вывода дочерних элементов контейнера друг под другом)

а самим дочерним элементам указать `order: значение;` с порядком расположения

```css
.main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.main > .header {order: 2; } /* Отобразится вторым */
.main > .content {order: 3; } /* Отобразится третьим */
.main > .menu {order: 1; } /* Отобразится первым  */
.main > .footer {order: 4; } /* Отобразится четвертым  */
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="header">1</div>
    <div class="content">2</div>
    <div class="menu">3</div>
    <div class="footer">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но высота блока может отличатся на страницах, к тому же она различная на разных разрешениях. Вариант с фиксированым смещением контента не подходит.

Comment: @АнтонБелоусов поправил ответ, возможно второй вариант поможет

Comment: Большое спасибо, думаю, это то, что нужно